# Wrap generic TypeScript function to pass through nulls

Tags: typescript

`Expression<T>` is a class that can evaluate to a `T`:

```
class Expression<T> {
  evaluate(): T {
    // ...
  }
}
```

`Expression` has a static `parse` method that parses an expression. Its second parameter indicates the expected type and determines the generic type of the returned `Expression`:

```
export interface RGBA {
  r: number;
  g: number;
  b: number;
  a: number;
}

interface TypeMap {
  string: string;
  number: number;
  color: RGBA;
  boolean: boolean;
  [other: string]: any;
}

export class Expression<T> {
  static parse<T extends expression.StylePropertyType>(
    expr: number | string | Readonly<StyleFunction> | Readonly<MapboxExpression>,
    expectedType?: T,
  ): Expression<TypeMap[T]> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

(Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/danvk/4378b6936f9cd634fc8c9f69c4f18b81), the context is [Mapbox style expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#case)).

This lets you parse expressions and evaluate them in a type-safe way:

```
const colorExp = Expression.parse("red", "color");  // type is Expression<RGBA>
const red = colorExp.evaluate();  // type is RGBA

const numExp = Expression.parse(["+", 1, 2], "number");  // type is Expression<number>
const num = numExp.evaluate();  // type is number
```

So far so good. Now I'd like to write a function that wraps `Expression.parse` to pass through `undefined` values. The implementation without types is simple:

```
const parseOrUndef = (expr, type) => expr === undefined ? undefined : Expression.parse(expr, type);
```

But what if I want the types? Ideally I'd have:

```
const colorExp = parseOrUndef("red", "color");  // type is Expression<RGBA> | undefined
const red = colorExp?.evaluate();  // type is RGBA | undefined

const numExp = parseOrUndef(["+", 1, 2], "number");  // type is Expression<number> | undefined
const num = numExp.evaluate();  // type is number | undefined
```

Is it possible to do this in TypeScript without copy/pasting all the types from `Expression.parse`? Here's one attempt:

```
type AddUndefToTuple<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? [First | undefined, ...Rest]
  : [];

const withUndef = <Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: Fn) => (
  ...args: AddUndefToTuple<Parameters<Fn>>
): ReturnType<Fn> | undefined => ((args as any)[0] === undefined ? undefined : fn(...args));

const parseOrUndef = withUndef(Expression.parse);
```

Unfortunately this results in `Expression<any>` because the relationship between the `type` parameter and the return type is lost when you split `Fn` into `Parameters<Fn>` and `Return<Fn>`:

```
const colorExp = parseOrUndef("red", "color");  // type is Expression<any> | undefined
const red = colorExp?.evaluate();  // type is any :(

const numExp = parseOrUndef(["+", 1, 2], "number");  // type is Expression<any> | undefined
const num = numExp?.evaluate();  // type is any :(
```

Is there a way to do this generically without losing this relationship? Or do I have to copy/paste the types from `Expression.parse`?

[Full Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyqA2EAKAnA9pFoAq5oF4AoKKAHygHIBjNeNFC4sygZ2BQEsA7Ac0ZPIUuAVwC2AIwgMmgiCNH9mFcWloQAhl0WCAZvVHrgwCABNtlDgZ4QKAbkKFQkKAFl1YFQA8Aop7AoIFhYONC4ofCgAbTZOXgAaKAA6ZM0QSIBddPtCbmMUHXUqaAAlAHEAIQBBKABvJhQALih5SRR7Eh4mlql2qHEusVbe9QGJHsIAXwdcqQKiqFxINzBaphjuTqh13l7uxubB8ZIaOn2yqt6VNU0mq8RNXsi0YAALKSbtnnSm1Pspwio8HUQSgvn8gWCoQAPNgAHyrEhsQwcKhQMDqFAsCAwqAQTzGLgmFiwBDIdCYHB4WEACiYJDx-lGrWYn2YxQ0JlC8BAUOWXjBASCIS48PIwkJEB03FMcTpuL8ECoxhMiwgAH4mthZSQAJRNAUQ4UwvDLSLYdLwuokEgBYDCFBhETweBQYGurggWzWqBMf70gBu6ngwkMEGpeoWCOttvtjuEztdxN+vsmDgA9GnQX5BZCuIl0ZiwzqoAB3egAayTxIZiuVDUIVqgNC4bCbtHoYPCWfBQtC+YxWOpACIAiYhwkhyd6EOdV6oBmoE5oBxiQbe1woedKrCmM3W6Ou1OUGDEhBA8HQ+G5wul1AV1At7vQq35J2Imvc-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-6ASBUDgZBhzA7OoM484EM9rmUIw2KcOuSYRPoZhYhgmjZ4Y5eLPzmD7N4yABOpkAA)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line `(...args: AddUndefToTuple<Parameters<Fn>>)`.

In order to infer exact literal type of arguments instead of putting just a type constraint, you need to infer them again with help of generics.

`parseOrUndef` returns function without generic. No generic - no inference.
[image]

Hence, in order to infer `"red"` and `"color"` arguments you need to add extra generic for them, `Expr` and `Type` accordingly.

Consider this example:

```js
type StylePropertyType =
  | 'color'
  | 'string'
  | 'number'
  | 'enum'
  | 'boolean'
  | 'formatted'
  | 'image';

type MapboxExpression = [string, ...any[]];

interface RGBA {
  r: number;
  g: number;
  b: number;
  a: number;
}

interface TypeMap {
  string: string;
  number: number;
  color: RGBA;
  boolean: boolean;
  [other: string]: unknown;
}

class Expression<T> {
  static parse<T extends StylePropertyType>(
    expr: number | string | Readonly<MapboxExpression> | undefined,
    expectedType?: T,
  ): Expression<TypeMap[T]> {
    return null as any;
  }

  evaluate(): T {
    return null as any;
  }
}

// But with withUndef wrapper does not:
type AddUndefToTuple<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? [First | undefined, ...Rest]
  : [];

const withUndef = <Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: Fn) =>
  <
    Expr extends Parameters<Fn>[0],
    Type extends Parameters<Fn>[1],
    >(
      ...args: [Expr, Type]
    ): Expression<TypeMap[Type]> | undefined =>
    ((args as any)[0] === undefined ? undefined : fn(...args));

const parseOrUndef = withUndef(Expression.parse);

const colorExp = parseOrUndef("red", "color");  // Expression<RGBA> | undefined
const red = colorExp?.evaluate();  // RGBA | undefined

const numExp = parseOrUndef(["+", 1, 2], "number");  // Expression<RGBA> | undefined
const num = numExp?.evaluate();  // number | undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyqA2EAKAnA9pFoAq5oF4AoKKAHygHIBjNeNFC4sygZ2BQEsA7Ac0ZPIUuAVwC2AIwgMmgiCNH9mFcWloQAhl0WCAZvVHrgwCABNtlDgZ4QKAbkKFQkKAFl1YFQA8Aop7AoIFhYONC4ofCgAbTZOXgAaKAA6ZM0QSIBddPtCbmMUHXUqaAAlAHEAIQBBKABvJhQALih5SRR7Eh4mlql2qHEusVbe9QGJHsIAXwdcqQKiqFxINzBaphjuTqh13l7uxubB8ZIaOn2yqt6VNU0mq8RNXsi0YAALKSbtnnSm4S4Aay4aAA7lx7FNCFR4OoglBfP5AsFQgAebAAPlWJDYhg4VCgYHUKBYEBRUAgnmMXBMLFgCGQ6EwODwqIAFEwSGT-KNWsxPsxihoTKF4CAkcsvHCAkEQlx0eRfiYIDpuKY4mzSX4IFRjCZFhAAPxNbCqkgASiaEoR0pReGWkWw6XRdRIJACwGEKDCIng8Cg0N9XBAvXB7IAbup4MJDBBmWaFhjna73Z7hN7fdTUkHJg4APTZqDlYTAKBAjivYull4AVUpiuLKHcmCggsCzWeDUceCglRMJmrCp02DQ2GEYEQJLJFKp-rSDvCcYncinkW4OikUAAYhxCcAEslEiu1-y2OkmHqopvt8x5YrlSZd8kj8ATyQmhlsjQuGxy68%207WIkj1zCBdKWpZk9wJHgWCaVIMhNcJ0VSFkdC4JpALg-BUSYJE1QldVJ2pJACXUUQIDyFgAJlSIAAZ0mNZ1dTwxcCKIkiyIo1FIgARlotUWTVEhwJQSDXwlBJdWfZ1YwtKVkV1W1xNlKBryVLhTHgtVmWZCD03TAMTWo9JwnwCJlNvKAz1M1STCgJpkLAlIhJYE0TXfUIv3xQkIAAeRQX8dDnEsfxrHRmWkxEuESDyiRchwPy-E56DhOcou83zguZAAiAITAyhIMoSlAMpckhc1hPxJXCpFzkqRTLNMCE3KLbK5wKuE9USCAwwjKMY1sEq82qq9gtvWLGoOUQkoiFKfL85lIgygBqXKoE4hIACZaKgDK9iKvqoFKsKrWq2rhqshrPyLeQ53kNqOq6yNjF6-rxu5OVTvqwggA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments), in my blog, you can find more examples with function arguments inference